# Fabricjs canvas any shapes

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

How could i implement customization for wall clock? I need to change canvas shape and limit objects inside canvas shapes. Is it possible? help me on this. for example,

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var w, h;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
w = canvas.width / 2;
h = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.save();
ctx.arc(w, h, 230, 0, Math.PI * 2,true);
```

Comment: [Reference](http://jsfiddle.net/mullainathan/xnr8kfx2/1/). After implementation of my project by using circle shape canvas, I'm struck with limiting objects inside context. I need a solution to limit any objects inside context.

Comment: ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); Canvas drawing area.

Comment: No, Look on this [reference](http://jsfiddle.net/mullainathan/xnr8kfx2/1/), Out of context any objects will be hide from visible.